# Printing out items in linkedList

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};

node *sentinel;
int numItem;


void pushBack(int new_data){

    sentinel = new node();

    while( (sentinel->next)!= NULL)
    {
        sentinel = sentinel->next;
    }

    node *toAdd = new node();
    toAdd->data = new_data;
    sentinel->next = toAdd;
    toAdd->next = NULL;
    numItem++;

}

void print(){




}

int main(){

    pushBack(1);
    pushBack(2);
    pushBack(3);
    pushBack(4);
    pushBack(5);
    print();


return 0;
}
```

I am implementing a pushBack() method which is to add items to the end of the linkedlist.
How to implement print() method in order to print out elements in linkedList?
My problem is I don't know how to start at the first index of linkedList.

Comment: do you have a starting node, the so called "head" of the list? that's your first node to print =) ... and I would not use the node "sentinel" as you did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually a lot deeper than just your `print()` function: your `push_back()` doesn't work the way you want it to work as far as I can tell! I strongly recommend you take a piece of paper and draw your list structure with the individual elements. Initially, you'd have an empty list:

```
=========
| head -+-->nil
=========
```

When inserting one element, you need to arrive at this structure, instead:

```
=========       ===========
| head -+------>|  data=1 |
=========       |  next --+-->nil
           nil<-+- prev   |
                ===========
```

Doing so only requires to create a new node and modify the head. Adding more nodes is a bit more interesting as you either need to also remember the last node or you need to walk the list to add something to its end. The picture after adding three nodes with data `1`, `2`, and `3` in this order should look something like this:

```
=========       ===========       ===========       ===========
| head -+------>|  data=1 |<-\/-->|  data=2 |<-\/-->|  data=3 |
=========       |  next --+--/\   |  next --+--/\   |  next --+->nil
           nil<-+- prev   |    \--+- prev   |    \--+- prev   |
                ===========       ===========       ===========
```

Coding this up is, obviously, done in `push_back()` but your current `push_back()` wouldn't yield this structure. Once you have this structure, you'd just start your `print()` with the `head` and print the respective `data` fields.